# SQL Server : Maximum value scenario for columns with type IDENTITY(1,1)

Tags: sql-server, rows, identity-column

I have a table Transaction schema defined as below

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions(
    Trans_ID [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
    Trans_Details varchar(43) 
    )
```

By the design you can guess i need to have unique values for each row. But what would happen if i keep on insert rows? As my Trans_ID is of type Int, would it take the max int range and fall back to 0 again? If yes, How should i maintain the uniqueness amount rows?

Thank you.

Comment: You plan to write 2 billion rows?

Comment: @nicomp Nothing special when system lives for many years

Comment: @lad2025 nah. I have 2 billion of many things.

Comment: @Ramu You can: a) change type to BIGINT b) update table and change values to `-1,-2,-3,-4...` so you get next 2 bilions rows (can be expensive operation)

Comment: @lad2025: it totally depends whether two billion is something special or not. It is for example special to sell more than 2 billion products but it's not so special if you measure something frequently over multiple years.

Comment: Not sure this should be marked as a duplicate... this one also asked "How should I handle things when the max is reached", which is not addressed in the other question.

Comment: Identity does not have any Cyclic behavior. So if you reached the maximum INT number, the next insert(s) will be failed. If you need to have cyclic behavior you can try SEQUENCE object Which is described here(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx). SEQUENCE has the same behavior as the Identity, but it can also has the cyclic behavior. Finally if you want to generate fully unique identifier without the concern of maximum value, you can think of UniqueIdentifier data type too.

Comment: @JeffreyVanLaethem. Yep. It depends on where the data will originate. If the db supports a single retail store where all transactions are entered by hand, then 2 billion is sufficient. If the db supports a sensor array taking measurements over time, then 2 billion might not be enough. Since the OP didn't specify, it's reasonable to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you reach the maximum INT value, the next insert will fail. It will not automatically reset to 0 or anything like that. But, since an Int in SQL Server goes from -2147483648 to 2147483647, you could always do:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (Transactions.Trans_ID, RESEED, -2147483648);
```

Which will give you double the identity values at least and has the benefit of not having to drop the table to change the column's data type if you're already in this situation :)

Comment: You guessed it right. Table already exists with data. Scenario is some transactions may sit idle in the table waiting to get a match for months together. I agree the range would double. Is there a way to check maxout stage apart from custom check to get row count and compare with Int range?

Comment: If you go on with this make sure that the app using the database can handle negative PK.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `bigint` such as :

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions(
    Trans_ID [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1),
    Trans_Details varchar(43) 
    )
```

That will give you 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807) possible rows.

Comment: Identity does not have any Cyclic behavior. So if you reached the maximum INT number, the next insert(s) will be failed. If you need to have cyclic behavior you can try SEQUENCE object Which is described here(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx). SEQUENCE has the same behavior as the Identity, but it can also has the cyclic behavior. Finally if you want to generate fully unique identifier without the concern of maximum value, you can think of UniqueIdentifier data type too.

Comment: @ForguesR : I need to make use of this table frequently, unfortunately mostly using joins. If i use bigint would that have any performance issues? Can you please throw some light? Thank you

Comment: @Ramu Well, if you really plan to reach 4B rows then you don't really have the choice. Using a `BIGINT` will then cost a 15 Go extra because you are using 8 bytes instead of 4 for the PK.  The table being bigger, the server will have to read more pages from disk.  So yes, there is a performance hit.  Use a `BIGINT` only if you really need it.

Comment: @ForguesR : Thank you for your time. Wish i could accept your solution as well. I doubt i can change the table schema at this point. But surely your suggestion will pass through my mind for future schema designs. Thanks again